# Using Requester Pays in line with pre-signed URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have lots of very large data sets that need to be distributed. Subscribers will be able to ask for a data set and then download it:

1. By a URL that will soon expire so it doesn't persist to be illegally spread.
2. Requester pays for the transfer as some of our data sets are in the range of 300GB - 1TB in bytes or we won't make ends meet if they download multiple times.

Basically, we need **requester pay** for the bandwidth / transfer of a **temporary URL**.

After we have enabled **Requester Pays** for our bucket, it seems it only works with plain object URLs?

And pre-signed URLs work even if requester gives NO `x-amz-request-payer: requester`?

Is there any way to make requester pay for pre-signed URLs so both features work together?

Answer (score 0):

The "requester" in "Requester Pays" refers to the AWS account that owns the credentials that were used to *generate* the signed URL... not whoever is *using* the signed URL.

It's not really intended for the application you're describing unless your customer is also an AWS customer who knows how to generate a requester pays signature.

Comment: So I guess there's no way to really protect us from download abusing?

Comment: it is the combination of Requester Pays + Pre-Signed URLs that doesn't work. To use Requester Pays, the requester must have their own AWS Account, from which they make the request and they will be billed for Data Transfer. In contrast, a pre-signed URL is generated by somebody who _does_ have permission to access the object and is given to somebody who _does not_ have access to the object. The person accessing the object is _anonymous_ so they cannot be billed. Another option is to create a temporary file, allow the user to download it via Requester Pays, then delete it after _n_ minutes.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it's a way to go but may still incur additional bills if we have lots of downloaders to our data. Too bad S3 doesn't handle symlinks.

Comment: Related: [How to create a signed s3 url for requester pays bucket in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61199204/174777) (Creator of pre-signed URL pays)