# How to create a signed s3 url for requester pays bucket in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a requester pays bucket that I do not control in form:

`s3://bucket-name/path-to-my-file`

I am attempting to generate a presigned url to send to a web app to render it in browser.

I've gone through the [`boto s3 documentation`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) but can't find anything that covers this :(

My script below creates returns URL that does not have access and returns this error from s3:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>11DCA24D8DF2E9E8</RequestId>
  <HostId>SeTDlt66hPsj5/dV1pOT9GnYyWgpSGI4ezI3wC7iz8Pny9sy2sUWsuUsl4JkEQeBXXIyiE8EXCk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I'm confident this is because the bucket is requester pays, becuase when I run this command in aws cli it works:

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://blackfynn-discover-use1/66/2/files/Derivatives . --request-payer requester --recursive
```

But this one returns `Forbidden`:

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://blackfynn-discover-use1/66/2/files/Derivatives .
```

Here's my python script which would work if it was not requester pays:

```py
import requests
import boto3

def get_signed_url(s3_url):
    # Get the service client.
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name, key_name = split_s3_bucket_key(s3_url)
    # Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket_name,
            'Key': key_name
        }
    )
    return url

def split_s3_bucket_key(s3_path):
    """Split s3 path into bucket and key prefix.
    This will also handle the s3:// prefix.
    :return: Tuple of ('bucketname', 'keyname')
    """
    if s3_path.startswith('s3://'):
        s3_path = s3_path[5:]
    return find_bucket_key(s3_path)

def find_bucket_key(s3_path):
    """
    This is a helper function that given an s3 path such that the path is of
    the form: bucket/key
    It will return the bucket and the key represented by the s3 path
    """
    s3_components = s3_path.split('/')
    bucket = s3_components[0]
    s3_key = ""
    if len(s3_components) > 1:
        s3_key = '/'.join(s3_components[1:])
    return bucket, s3_key

s3_file_path = 's3://blackfynn-discover-use1/66/2/files/Derivatives/manifest.xlsx'
get_signed_url(s3_file_path)
```

Comment: Pre-signed URLs do not, and cannot, identify the requester (they identify the signer). How would requester pays work in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the URL will need to include `x-amz-request-payer=requester`, but this might also need to be specified when creating the pre-signed URL.

Try the advice shown below, then let us know whether it worked for you!

From [Downloading Objects in Requester Pays Buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html):

> For signed URLs, include `x-amz-request-payer=requester` in the request

From [Support Requester Pays S3 buckets · Issue #346 · samtools/htslib](https://github.com/samtools/htslib/issues/346):

> OK, was able to compile htslib with good libcurl support. Confirmed that it can take a presigned URL to view files:

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
url  = client.generate_presigned_url("get_object", Params={"Bucket":"angel-reqpay","Key":"test.cram" , "RequestPayer":'requester'})
```

From [AWS Developer Forums: Announcing “Requester Pays” Option for ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=27622):

> You URL would look something like:

```
http://somebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key/[.....]&x-amz-request-payer=requester
```

Comment: UPDATE: I have done some testing and can confirm that the middle example (in Python) works well. I tested this creating a Requester Pays bucket in Account A, then making an object public. Then, in Account B, I ran the above Python code (with my bucket name and key) and the resulting URL worked successfully.

Comment: This was a fun topic to explore, so I wrote a blog post that goes into more details on the topic: [S3 Pre-signed URLs for Requester Pays buckets - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/s3-pre-signed-urls-for-requester-pays-buckets-55nc)